# Projection on closed convex $K \subset L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Yesterday I was dealing with this exercise:

let $K := \{f \in L^2(0,1) : f\ge 0 \}$. Show that K is a closed convex set and that $P_K(f) = f^+$ (Positive part of f).

I already proved that $K$ is convex and closed cause it's trivial to verify that
\begin{equation}
[f,g] = \{\lambda f + (1-\lambda)g\} \subset K
\end{equation}

and also if $\{f_n\}_n \subset K$,  $f_n \ge 0$  $\forall n$ and $f = lim_n f_n$ then $f \ge 0$. But to find the orthogonal projection of $f$ on $K$ I should study

\begin{equation}
inf_{g \in K} ||f-g||_2 = inf_{g \ge 0} \int_0^1 |f-g|^2
\end{equation}

How should I go on to prove that it coincides to $f^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in K$ then 
\begin{align}
||f-g||_2 &= \int_0^1 |f-g|^2\\
& = \int_0^1 |f^+-f^--g|^2 \\
&= \int_0^1 |-f^-+(f^+-g)|^2\\
&\text{(Hint: This follows from definitions of $f^+, f^-$)} \\
&=  \int_0^1 (|-f^-|+|(f^+-g)|)^2 \\
&\geq \int_0^1 (|-f^-|)^2\\
& =\int_0^1 |f-f^+|^2\\
& = ||f-f^+||_2
\end{align}

Hence after taking infimum over all $g \in K$ we get,

$inf_{g\in K} ||f-g||_2=||f-f^+||_2$

Comment: Ok you mean that we obtain $||f-g||_2 \ge ||f-f^+||_2$ and taking the infimum between all $g \in K$ we get $||f-g||_2 = ||f-f^+||_2$ right? Thank you very much.

Comment: After taking the infimum we get $inf_{g\in K} ||f-g||_2=||f-f^+||_2$

Comment: BTW workout details of step where I have given hint.